# Arduino serial communication

Tags: arduino

Since I changed my motor controller whenever a motor goes into reverse it doesn't brake when it's supposed to...

moving forward, is fine, it runs as long as I am holding the button on the console app.
turning left/right, the motor that is reversing will run without stopping.
moving backward, both will run without stopping.

```
    // Firmware for the Android Shield Board for tank robots
// Pan/tilt servos now work: 0 pin off, 255 pin on, 1~254 8 bit granularity servo movement (5 microseconds).
#define PwmPinMotorA 11
#define PwmPinMotorB 6
#define DirectionPinMotorA 3
#define DirectionPinMotorB 5
#define ServoPin1 0
#define ServoPin2 0
#define ServoFlip1 false
#define ServoFlip2 false

#define mySerialSpeed 9600 // arduino 2009: 4800 or lower!
#define debugSerialSpeed 9600 // arduino 2009: 4800 or lower!
#define BufferLength 16
#define LineEnd1 13
#define LineEnd2 10
#define ServoTimingStep 5
#define ServoCenter 1500
#define ServoTimingFloor ServoCenter-(127*ServoTimingStep)

//#define serialout
#define debugout

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 255); // rx only

char charin = 80;
char inputBuffer[BufferLength];
int value = 128;
int speed = 128;
int timer = 15;
int timermax = 15;
int inputLength = 0;
int servoval1 = 127;
int servoval2 = 127;
int tempval1, tempval2;

void setup()
{
  // motor pins must be outputs
  pinMode(PwmPinMotorA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PwmPinMotorB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DirectionPinMotorA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DirectionPinMotorB, OUTPUT);
  mySerial.begin(mySerialSpeed); 
#ifdef debugout
  Serial.begin(debugSerialSpeed);
#endif
}

// process a command string
void HandleCommand(char* input, int length)
{
#ifdef debugout
  Serial.print(">");
  Serial.print(input);
  Serial.print("<");
  Serial.print(length);
  Serial.println("|");
#endif
  if (length < 1) { // not a valid command
    return;
  }
  // calculate number following command (d10~d255)
  if (length > 1) {
    value = atoi(&input[1]);
    if (value > 255)
      value = 255;
    if (value < 0)
      value = 0;
    switch(input[0])
    {
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
      if (value > 127)
        value = 127;
      speed = value*2; 
      break;
    case '/':
      timermax = value; 
      break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
      #ifdef ServoFlip1
      servoval1 = 256 - value; 
      #else
      servoval1 = value; 
      #endif
      break;
    case 'v':
    case 'V':
      #ifdef ServoFlip2
      servoval2 = 256 - value; 
      #else
      servoval2 = value; 
      #endif
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }

  timer = timermax;

  int* command = (int*)input;
  // check commands
  // note that the two bytes are swapped, ie 'RA' means command AR



  switch(*command) {


  case '2':
  case '2j':
  case '2J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
    break;

  case '8':
  case '8j':
  case '8J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
    break;

  case '6':
  case '6j':
  case '6J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
    break;

  case '4':
  case '4j':
  case '4J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
    break;

  case '9':
  case '9j':
  case '9J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
    break;

  case '1':
  case '1j':
  case '1J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
    break;

  case '3':
  case '3j':
  case '3J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
    break;

  case '7':
  case '7j':
  case '7J':
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
    break;

  default: // stop, just to be safe
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, 0);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
    analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, 0);
    digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
    break;

  }  
} 

void loop()
{ 
  // get a command string form the mySerial port
  inputLength = 0;
  do {
    while (!mySerial.available()){
      // note: arduino cannot handle fullduplex on myserial so no output here!

      // do servos here
      tempval1 = (servoval1*ServoTimingStep) + ServoTimingFloor;
      tempval2 = (servoval2*ServoTimingStep) + ServoTimingFloor;
      if (servoval1 > 0)
        digitalWrite(ServoPin1,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(tempval1);
      if (servoval1 < 255)
        digitalWrite(ServoPin1,LOW);
      if (servoval2 > 0)
        digitalWrite(ServoPin2,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(tempval2);
      if (servoval2 < 255)
        digitalWrite(ServoPin2,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(5000 - tempval1 - tempval2);
      delay(15); // reduce/remove if we're doing more things here

      // decrease the timer
      if (--timer < 0)
      { 
        timer=0;
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, 0);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, 0);
      }
    }; 

    // wait for input 
    {
      charin = mySerial.read(); // read it in
#ifdef debugout
        Serial.print(charin);
        tempval1 = charin;
        Serial.println(tempval1);
#endif

      if ((charin > 46 && charin < 58) || (charin=='d') || (charin=='j') || (charin=='c') || (charin=='v'))
      {
        inputBuffer[inputLength]=charin;
        inputLength++;

#ifdef serialout
        mySerial.print("$PD,11,");
        mySerial.print(timer);
        mySerial.print(",");
        mySerial.print(value);
        mySerial.println("*");
#endif
      }

    }
  } 
  while (charin>46 && charin<119 && charin != LineEnd1 && charin != LineEnd2 && inputLength < BufferLength);
  inputBuffer[inputLength] = 0; //  add null terminator
  HandleCommand(inputBuffer, inputLength);
}
```

Comment: can you isolate the code with which you are having a problem?

Comment: Sorry I know it is a lot of code, but I am unable to isolate the problem. When recieving 8j the motors run for a second when recieving 2j they run continuously.

Comment: The larger the code the less likely people are to help you. To get good answers you really need to narrow it down to a small area or hope for someone feeling very generous with their time.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your code  in Arduino 1.0, and ran it on my Pro Mini 16MHz 328 with these modifications:

```
//#define debugout

HardwareSerial mySerial = Serial;
```

and ran it on my Mega 16MHz 2560 with these modifications:

```
#define PwmPinMotorA 7

//#define debugout

HardwareSerial mySerial = Serial;
```

and it seems to work fine (judging by the code and the results on my oscilloscope).

I have been using SoftwareSerial to talk to my GPS and I noticed that it had strange errors if I ever ran it at 9600 baud. I had to run at 4800 to get seamless communication.

Obviously this does not explain why your --timer<0 would be ignored. I would recommend rewriting it so that timer function is always handled like:

```
unsigned long timeout   = 2000;  // 2 seconds
unsigned long clrtime   = 0;
boolean       timecheck = false;

// ... upon command set the event
clrtime = millis() + timeout;
timecheck = true;

// ... every loop check for event
if (timecheck && millis() > clrtime) 
{
  timecheck = false;
  analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, 0);
  analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, 0);
}
```

This is a safer way of handling the timed event. Be careful not to overwrite Timer0, which Arduino uses for delay(), delayMicroseconds(), micros(), and millis(). I would also recommend swapping pins 3 and 6 to keep Timer2 as the source for both. Here is the final code that I tested:

```
// Firmware for the Android Shield Board for tank robots
// Pan/tilt servos now work: 0 pin off, 255 pin on, 1~254 8 bit granularity 
// servo movement (5 microseconds).



// Required Libraries //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





// Pin Mapping /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Arduino 3  [PD3](INT1/OC2B) OC2B (Timer/Counter2 Output Compare Match B Output)
// Arduino 4  [PD4](XCK/T0)    T0 (Timer/Counter 0 External Counter Input)
// Arduino 5  [PD5](T1/OC0B)   T1 (Timer/Counter 1 External Counter Input)
//                             OC0B (Timer/Counter0 Output Compare Match B Output)
// Arduino 6  [PD6](AIN0/OC0A) OC0A (Timer/Counter0 Output Compare Match A Output)
// Arduino 8  [PB0](ICP/CLKO)  ICP1 (Timer/Counter1 Input Capture Input)
// Arduino 9  [PB1](OC1A)      OC1A (Timer/Counter1 Output Compare Match A Output)
// Arduino 10 [PB2](SS/OC1B)   OC1B (Timer/Counter1 Output Compare Match B Output)
// Arduino 11 [PB3](MOSI/OC2)  OC2A (Timer/Counter2 Output Compare Match A Output)
  #define PwmPinMotorA 11
  #define PwmPinMotorB 3        // SWAPPED!
  #define DirectionPinMotorA 6  // SWAPPED!
  #define DirectionPinMotorB 5
  #define ServoPin1 0
  #define ServoPin2 0
  #define ServoFlip1 false
  #define ServoFlip2 false





// Global Macros ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  #define mySerialSpeed 9600 // arduino 2009: 4800 or lower!
  #define debugSerialSpeed 9600 // arduino 2009: 4800 or lower!
  #define BufferLength 16
  #define LineEnd1 13
  #define LineEnd2 10
  #define ServoTimingStep 5
  #define ServoCenter 1500
  #define ServoTimingFloor ServoCenter-(127*ServoTimingStep)





// Global Variables ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  HardwareSerial mySerial = Serial;

  char charin = 80;
  char inputBuffer[BufferLength];
  int value = 128;
  int speed = 128;
  int inputLength = 0;
  int servoval1 = 127;
  int servoval2 = 127;
  int tempval1, tempval2;
  unsigned long timeout   = 2000;  // 2 seconds
  unsigned long clrtime   = 0;
  boolean       timecheck = false;




// Hardware Setup //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  void setup()
  {
    // motor pins must be outputs
    pinMode(PwmPinMotorA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PwmPinMotorB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DirectionPinMotorA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DirectionPinMotorB, OUTPUT);
    mySerial.begin(mySerialSpeed); 
  }
  // setup()





// Main Code ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  void loop()
  { 
    // get a command string form the mySerial port
    inputLength = 0;
    do {
      while (!mySerial.available()){
        // note: arduino cannot handle fullduplex on myserial so no output here!

        // do servos here
        tempval1 = (servoval1*ServoTimingStep) + ServoTimingFloor;
        tempval2 = (servoval2*ServoTimingStep) + ServoTimingFloor;
        if (servoval1 > 0)
          digitalWrite(ServoPin1,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(tempval1);
        if (servoval1 < 255)
          digitalWrite(ServoPin1,LOW);
        if (servoval2 > 0)
          digitalWrite(ServoPin2,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(tempval2);
        if (servoval2 < 255)
          digitalWrite(ServoPin2,LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(5000 - tempval1 - tempval2);
        delay(15); // reduce/remove if we're doing more things here

        // handle the timeout
        if (timecheck && millis() > clrtime) 
        {
          timecheck = false;
          analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, 0);
          analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, 0);
        }
      }; 

      // wait for input 
      {
        charin = mySerial.read(); // read it in

        if ((charin > 46 && charin < 58) || (charin=='d') || 
            (charin=='j') || (charin=='c') || (charin=='v'))
        {
          inputBuffer[inputLength]=charin;
          inputLength++;
        }

      }
    } 
    while (charin>46 && charin<119 && charin != LineEnd1 && 
           charin != LineEnd2 && inputLength < BufferLength);
    inputBuffer[inputLength] = 0; //  add null terminator
    HandleCommand(inputBuffer, inputLength);
  }
  // loop()





// Local Methods ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // process a command string
  void HandleCommand(char* input, int length)
  {
    if (length < 1) { // not a valid command
      return;
    }
    // calculate number following command (d10~d255)
    if (length > 1) {
      value = atoi(&input[1]);
      if (value > 255)
        value = 255;
      if (value < 0)
        value = 0;
      switch(input[0])
      {
      case 'd':
      case 'D':
        if (value > 127)
          value = 127;
        speed = value*2; 
        break;
      case '/':
        timeout = 100 * value; 
        break;
      case 'c':
      case 'C':
        #ifdef ServoFlip1
        servoval1 = 256 - value; 
        #else
        servoval1 = value; 
        #endif
        break;
      case 'v':
      case 'V':
        #ifdef ServoFlip2
        servoval2 = 256 - value; 
        #else
        servoval2 = value; 
        #endif
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }

    clrtime = millis() + timeout;
    timecheck = true;

    int* command = (int*)input;
    // check commands
    // note that the two bytes are swapped, ie 'RA' means command AR



    switch(*command) {

      case '2':
      case '2j':
      case '2J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
        break;

      case '8':
      case '8j':
      case '8J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
        break;

      case '6':
      case '6j':
      case '6J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
        break;

      case '4':
      case '4j':
      case '4J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
        break;

      case '9':
      case '9j':
      case '9J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, HIGH);
        break;

      case '1':
      case '1j':
      case '1J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
        break;

      case '3':
      case '3j':
      case '3J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, HIGH);
        break;

      case '7':
      case '7j':
      case '7J':
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, speed);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
        break;

      default: // stop, just to be safe
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorA, 0);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorA, LOW);
        analogWrite(PwmPinMotorB, 0);
        digitalWrite(DirectionPinMotorB, LOW);
        break;

    }  
  }
```

Because I cannot cause the same error you had, I can't tell if this fixes the problem. Good luck.